# is "Sound Bake" node here in 2.1.4 Animation node

Tags: animation-nodes

I can't find find Sound bake node in 2.1.4 do you know if it an other name or is just not here for now ?
thank's, have a good day

Comment: How would this change the workflow outlined here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47337/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-a-curve-and-or-a-mesh-from-a-wavefile

Answer (score 1):

You can't bake sound anymore, bc. you don't have to. Sound input is now live. It's a bit tricky, bc. it's not directly a node. 
Go to the VSE, drop a sound file wherever you want (meaning the start frame).
Back in the AN SHIFT A -> sound -> sound from sequence.
From there it gets processed in realtime, no more baking required.