# How to Convert a Sound WAV File to a 3D Mesh STL in Blender

Tags: animation, mesh, node-editor, audio

I'm trying to devise a way to generate a 3D mesh solid STL file from a WAV audio file so I can carve it on a CNC router and make a piece of artwork.

I am aware of [this answered question on Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47337/is-there-any-way-i-can-make-a-curve-and-or-a-mesh-from-a-wavefile), but since the answer is a few years old, the current version of Blender does not have the same-named nodes in the Animation Nodes add-on as those referenced in the directions from 2016 (e.g "Sound Bake" and "Spline from Points" are gone or re-named). Thus I am struggling to replicate the answer.

I'm hoping that someone can advise me here about how to adjust these steps in the current version of Blender (2.80.75) with Animation Nodes Add-On:

> You can do that with the Animation Nodes (AN) addon.
>
> 1) Make a new AN tree.
>
> 2) Make a Sound Bake node and load your sound. Then click on "Bake".
>
> 3) Create an "Evaluate Sound" node and set its Frame Type from Offset to
>   Absolute. The sound object you baked should be selected automatically.
>
> 4) Create "Loop Input" node and connect the Index socket to the Frame
>   input.
>
> 5) Click on the plus icon next to New Generator Output and type "Vector
>   List". This should create a new node that you can move to the right.
>
> 6) Connect the "Strength" output socket with the "Vector" input. A new
>   "Combine Vector" node should appear inbetween, because a vector
>   consists of 3 values and the Strength is only a single value.
>   Reconnect the sockets like in the image below.
>
> 7) Insert an optional Math node to be able to control the width of the
>   curve.
>
> 8) Create a "Invoke Subprogram" node and choose the loop you just
>   created. Then set the Iterations socket to the number of frames you
>   want to have in the final curve (too high numbers can slow Blender
>   down, you may want to uncheck "Always" in the toolbar so that AN
>   doesn't recreate the curve multiple times every second)
>
> 9) Create a "Spline from Points" node and connect it to the Vector List
>   output of the other node.
>
> 10)Create a "Set Splines on Object" node. Then click on the little plus
>   icon which will create an empty curve object in your scene that you
>   can use as output object. The last step is to take the Spline we
>   created before and put it on the Curve object. If you do this
>   connection a "Create List" node gets inserted automatically because
>   the Set Splines on Object node expects multiple splines (but we only
>   have one, so we create a list with one spline).
>
> 11) Now you should see the curve in the viewport. You can just remove all
>   nodes now or just make a copy of the curve in order to edit it
>   further.

Or, if perhaps there is an updated way to do this?

What I envision as my desired end result with the STL 3D mesh is that the X axis would be time of the sound file, and the Y axis would be first the WAV-form amplitude as shown in a DAW such as Ableton or Audacity, and then moving out in Y would be different frequency ranges (perhaps by dividing the sound into 16?). The Z would be amplitude.

And then I would be able to export the STL file and manipulate it as needed in Fusion360 or SketchUp to get it into my CNC router.

Thanks.

Comment: As seen in link, looked into this a while back, never bothered updating answer.   Came to the conclusion of using 3rd party tool like ffmpeg to create the sound surface image or data set..  See examples here http://lukaprincic.si/development-log/ffmpeg-audio-visualization-tricks  Eg the spectrum image can be used as a displacement map.  pyffmpeg is a very good python wrapper for doing this.  (aubio is also very good imo)  Both are, in my tests, at least  10x quicker to "bake" the audio than using blender's bake sound to fcurve operator.