# Geometry Nodes: How can I use baked sound F-curve data as a math function?

Tags: geometry-nodes, audio, fcurves

I want to use baked sound F-curve instead of sin and cos in expression for Trefoil knot:

\begin{aligned}x&=\sin t+2\sin 2t\\y&=\cos t-2\cos 2t\\z&=-\sin 3t\end{aligned}

Is it possible to set position of curve in Geometry Nodes using F-curve data as function?

Method I tried: recreate curve shape with simulation. Baked f-curve input as "Signal":

[image]

Then i tried to call the Z coordinate of the resulting curve for the given index.

[image]

I thought that I could replace sin with this group as a math function. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I think there might be a way to copy it as a driver and use that in GN

Comment: That sounds good. But I haven't found how to do it yet.

Answer (score 1):

- create a value node and right click (or press i) and add a keyframe
  [image]
  [image]
- then open up the graph editor and select the keyframe
- select `Channel > Bake Sound to F-Curves`
  [image]
- then locate your audio file and select it.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. This method allows you to get the value of the baked sound at a certain point in time. But I'm looking for a way to create the curve of the entire track at once. Found a solution using Animation nodes:
[https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47402/162404](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47402/162404)
It remains only to figure out how to do it using Geometry Nodes.

Comment: Even though it didn't answer the OP's question, this answered my question of how to bake a sound to an F-curve to a value.