# Baking sound to F-curve in keyframe produces no results

Tags: keyframes, baking, audio, fcurves

I want to animate a shader node from a sound file (showing an open or closed mouth if the sound crosses a threshold). I follow the suggestions [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304520/how-to-make-baked-sound-f-curve-trigger-a-layers-visibility), [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299266/geometry-nodes-how-can-i-use-baked-sound-f-curve-data-as-a-math-function) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305252/value-node-keyframe-missing-in-graph-editor/305254#305254), but the graph editor shows nothing in the result. I tried with a WAV and an MP3 file. Here is a GIF showing my process:

[image: screencast of baking sound to f-curves]

I'm new to Blender, and the threads above suggest this feature works out-of-the-box, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but what is it?

### Update after <kbd>HOME</kbd> key

Following one answer, I press the  <kbd>HOME</kbd> key after baking the sound. Baking had some result, as the editor zooms out and shows crosses at the expected length (24 frames per second times length of the track), but it does not show a curve. I also pressed the "Normalize" button at the top left:

[image: screenshot after HOME and Normalize]

The track has synthetic speech at about -16 dB. You can find it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11WDSoCmmdTTSQTkNE1Enl_5uc2G4SuU8/view?usp=drive_link). And I confirm that it has audio, as in this screenshot from Audacity:

[image]

I also tried with a different track, a longer one in MP3, and the result is the same.

### Second update

It seems that all the steps are correct and it may be my Blender version that is faulty. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TmPzaP628rtSiaI82MeJ-z38TfgJOScy/view?usp=drive_link) is a file started from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing everything correctly, and the operator works fine. You just need to press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to zoom out and see the entirety of the baked curve. It's normal for a sound file to start with silence, so you won't see audio fluctuations at the default current zoom level.

---

**Audio File Test**

I was able to bake the sound to an F-curve. A screenshot is attached below. I tested in version 3.6.0 and 4.0 (the operator name was changed to *Sound to Samples*).

[image: Test]

The steps I followed are:

1. Open Blender and switch to the Animation Workspace.
2. Select the Cube and add a Location Keyframe.
3. Switch the Dope Sheet to a Graph Editor.
4. Run *Channel > Bake Sound to F-Curves* and select the sound file.
5. Press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key.

---

**Screenshots from the shared file**

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Thank you! It still failed and I added an update. Shall I upload the Blender file to see if it's some error other than user error?

Comment: @miguelmorin I am more suspicious of the audio file. Can you verify that it has audio? I can try it on my side if you can share it. One thing you can try is to press the *Normalize* button on the top left of your second screenshot. It will switch to an alternative view that fits the graph into the 0 to 1 range, so even if the audio is very quiet, it should show something. If it doesn't, then there is probably no audio, and you should try the file in an audio player to verify.

Comment: Thank you! I confirm that the track has audio and updated the question with a link to it.

Comment: @miguelmorin I updated my answer with the steps I followed to test the sound file. It works as expected for me. Please follow the same steps in a new blend file to verify that everything works.

Comment: Thank you! I did the steps from scratch again and I have the same issue. I also rendered the file to see if the F-curve was baked but not showing, but no, the animation is static. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TmPzaP628rtSiaI82MeJ-z38TfgJOScy/view?usp=drive_link) is the file; can you please confirm that it works for you? If so, I need to reinstall Blender or change systems.

Comment: I opened the file, and the baked curve was there. I attached screenshots to my answer. I don't know what could be the source of this issue, but a fresh install could help us figure it out. Can you also try to lower the threshold of your setup to below 0.3? As you can see from my second screenshot, the audio doesn't go past 0.35.

Comment: Thank you very much! It turns out that Blender 3.4 on macOS High Sierra (10.13) doesn't deal well with F-curves, but I tried on a different system Linux Ubuntu, and now it works. So I was doing everything right, but the hardware was too old for the software.

Comment: You're welcome! That's great to hear. I wish you the best in your project.